# gstreamer initialization (gst_init) increases memory usage by 47 MB

Tags: c++, memory, gstreamer

We've been using (lib)gstreamer to do some RTSP streaming stuff. So far, so good. It works and we got it all up an running. However, I noticed that after `gst_init` being called, memory usage increases a lot. I reproduced this by making a very simple program that does nothing else.

So, before the call to `gst_init`, the memory usage is around 6 MB, and then right after it, it's like 53 MB.

**Does anyone know what is causing this large memory usage increase and how we might prevent it?**

I've checked which extra modules (libraries) are being loaded from `gst_init` and that sums up to like 5 MB, so that can't be the issue. I also checked the gstreamer source code, but couldn't really find what was causing the issue.

The memory usage is just too much.

**EDIT**:
Because someone asked it in the questions. It's going to run on a security system. The hardware is usually old and slow. With slow I mean, usually still running XP, 2-4 GB memory, 32 bit and not even an i3. It runs 24h a day and there are more applications running on the same system that are using the limited amount of memory. The less memory an application uses, the more we have for others.

Comment: Why is it too much? 53MB in this day and age is not much at all.

Comment: In our environment it is ;)

Comment: What is your environment?  These are important details you should mention in your question. Also what compiler are you using?

Comment: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-Gst.html#gst-init Looks like it loads "plug-ins", maybe you can disable plug-ins you are not using.

Comment: @TonyTheLion I'd be concerned by a 6mb -> 47mb memory usage too. If every program is so lax about memory use, and I multitask 10 of them, that's 470mb used!

Comment: @TonyTheLion, I have added details to the original question.

Comment: @NeilKirk, as said, I have looked at how large each plugin DLL is, and that adds up to like ~5MB, but it could indeed be that one of the plugins allocates this amount of memory.

Comment: Seems that you need to remove all plugins and add them back one by one to track that down :/